# How can I convert date/time into human readable form in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying code snippet in React. How can I make the created_at attribute in human-readable form in react just like in PHP laravel framework provides us diffForHumans() function to do so?

```
<div className="media-body">
      <h3 className="mt-0"><a href="">{question.title}</a></h3>
      <p className="lead">
            Asked By
            <a href="{question.user.url}" className={"px-2"}> 
              {question.user.name}
            </a>
            <small className="text-muted px-1">{question.created_at}
           </small>

        </p>
        <p className="small">{question.body.substring(0, 250) + '...'}</p>
        <hr/>
</div>
```

You can see the full code here: https://codepen.io/osman-rafi/pen/ZEzdozJ

In `<small className="text-muted px-1">{question.created_at}</small>` provies output like 2019-09-26 08:26:18, but i want in more readable form like '2 days ago' or 'one hour ago'.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use momentJs https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with `momentjs`.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

```
<small className="text-muted px-1">{moment(question.created_at).fromNow()}</small>
```